# Objective-C/Cocos2D - CCAnimate actionWithSpriteSequence - Don´t understand @"a00%02d.png"

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Can somebody help me with plist and

```
[CCAnimate actionWithSpriteSequence:@"a00%02d.png" numFrames:10]
```

I have a plist with 3 different Animations for my Character.

```
     first Animation: a0001.png - a0010.png,
     second Animation: a0011.png - a0020.png,
     third Animation: a0021.png - a0030.png
```

Now i want to show the second Animation…

For the first Animation it works.

But i don´t understand the behavior of @"a00%02d.png".

I looked at forums but they only do one Animation. So they don't have to change @"a00%02d.png".

Is it possible at all to do it this way??

It would be great if somebody could tell me!!

Comment: Any chance you can just name the images consecutively (a1.png, a2.png, etc)? Because that makes the format string a whole lot simpler: @"a%d.png". Ever since operating systems added natural sorting to the file system viewers (like 10 years ago), prefixing numbered files with leading 0s has become utterly unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

That's an `NSString` formatting issue you're running into:

`%02d` means a 2-place integer, so that whatever number you put in (i.e., 4) is written as a two-character string (i.e., 04) rather than just '4' as it would otherwise do.

So `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a00%02d.png", 5]` becomes a0005.png.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a00%02d.png", 21]` becomes a0021.png

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a00%02d.png", 196]` becomes a0096.png (which is *wrong*!)

**SO** the best thing really is to use:

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%04d.png", 196]` which becomes **a0196.png**

Comment: I think the thing you're missing is that you don't ever have to change your format string in this case, just the image number that you pass in.

Comment: BTW it is equivalent to the more flexible format @"a%04d.png". I suggest using this instead. That one even works for numbers lager than 99.

Comment: Thanks @HermannKlecker, updated to reflect that very good point